# Google Cloud AutoML Natural Language for Chatbot like application

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-automl, google-cloud-nl, google-cloud-automl-nl

I want to develop a chatbot like application which gives response to input questions using Google Cloud Platform.

Naturally, Dialogflow is suited for this such applications. But due to business conditions, I cannot use Dialogflow.

An alternative could be AutoML Natural Language, where I do not need much machine learning expertise.

AutoML Natural Language requires documents which are labelled. These documents can be used for training a model.

My example document:

```
What is cost of Swiss tour?
Estimate of Switzerland tour?
```

I would use a label such as Switzerland_Cost for this document.

Now, in my application I would have a mapping between Labels and Responses.

During Prediction, when I give an input question to the trained model, I would get a predicted label. I can then use this label to return the mapped response.

Is there a better approach to my scenario?

Answer (score 0):

I'm from Automl team. This seems like a good approach to me. People use Automl NL for intent detection, which is pretty aligned with what you try to do here.